what is the private key?
I have difficulty understanding your explanation...(see link  How to use the Gmail API, OAuth2 for Apps Script, and Domain-Wide Delegation to set email signatures for users in a G Suite domain)
because I tried to launch my test...it doesn't work and I got 2 error messages:

"failed to authenticate as user xxxxxx@xxxx.com"

"Exception: Invalid argument: key"


So what exactly does “the private key” correspond to ?
how could we find it in the email delegation formula ?
thank you in advance for your answer.
sincerely

Please edit your question and include your code.

The private key is like a password its used to compute a digital signature that can be used to verified by the corresponding public key.
Cryptographic keys are used for authorization of a service account with Google.
in the place of access tokens and refresh tokens.
